# Detect RAID Hardware or Software on Debian

Tags: linux, debian

Are there any way to detect if my server (on debian 6) is using RAID by Hardware or Software?. I have used some command but my server do not recognize them.

```
/proc/mdstat
omreport storage vdisk
cat /proc/mdstat
```

The commands upside is the only one that I have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For hardware, try

`lspci -vv | grep -i raid`.

For software, try the mdadm utility. It is used to manage MD devices (or Linux Software RAID). In particular, try its query command. The mdadm manpage says

> This will find out if a given device is a RAID array, or is part of one, and will provide brief information about the device.

You can get a list of devices in /dev with `ls -a /dev` and then use

`mdadm --query /dev/DEVICENAME`

Sources:

hardware: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139271/how-to-get-details-of-raid-devices-both-soft-and-hard

software: https://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm